# Insert duplicate records and relate them to each other

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Here are the tables I'm working with:.
1. `EMP_DAILY_SALARY (ID, DATE, WORKING_HOURS)`
2. `EMP_SALARY_PAID ( ID, DATE, WORKING_HOURS, HOURLY_COST_SALARY_PAID)`
3. `EMP_HOURLY_COST_ADJUSTMENT (ID ,HOURLY_COST, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE)`
4. `COST_ADJUSTMENT_LOG ( ID, OLD_HOURLY_COST, NEW_HOURLY_COST)`

According to the current situation we receive daily working hours on the same basis salary to be paid for the day is decided and paid at the end of the month.

Whenever we have update in `HOURLY_COST` we update it for the said period by using a procedure (already developed) and Salary is paid accordingly.
The data is received in `.txt` files and uploaded to tables.

Now we are working on a scenario that what if we come across following scenarios:-
1. Duplicate cost adjustment record received for same `ID` for same `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` **with same hourly cost**.
2. Duplicate cost adjustments record received for same `ID` for same `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` **with different hourly cost**.
3. What if we recieve a cost adjustment record and that is already adjusted?

One approach which I decided was to store all such records into a separate table. But I am finding it difficult relate them to each other. I need this relation prepared so that we can generate a report on the same.

Comment: The most obvious thing (to me, at least) is to relate them on ID, FROM_DATE and TO_DATE; don't you think?

Comment: All of those tables have an ID column. Is that the Employee's ID or the primary key for each table?

Comment: It is an Employee ID and a primary key also.

Comment: You can give suggestions on table structure also.